# Strict Standards: Declaration of '' should be compatible with ''

Tags: php

I have the following code.

```
if(!defined('mnminclude')){header('Location: ../404error.php');die();}

    include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/ez_sql_core.php');
    include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/dbconnect.php');

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Author: Justin Vincent (justin@visunet.ie)
    *  Web...: http://php.justinvincent.com
    *  Name..: ezSQL_mysql
    *  Desc..: mySQL component (part of ezSQL databse abstraction library)
    *
    */

    /**********************************************************************
    *  ezSQL error strings - mySQL
    */

    $ezsql_mysql_str = array
    (
        1 => '<h2>Error establishing a database connection!</h2><ol><li>Are you sure you have the correct user/password?<li>Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname?<li>Are you sure that the database server is running?<li>Have you run the <a href = "./install/install.php">Pligg Installer?</a></ol>',
        2 => 'Error establishing mySQL database connection. Correct user/password? Correct hostname? Database server running?',
        3 => 'Require $dbname to select a database',
        4 => 'MySQL database connection is not active',
        5 => 'Unexpected error while trying to select database'
    );

    /**********************************************************************
    *  ezSQL Database specific class - mySQL
    */

    if ( ! function_exists ('mysql_connect') ) die('<b>Fatal Error:</b> ezSQL_mysql requires mySQL Lib to be compiled and or linked in to the PHP engine');
    if ( ! class_exists ('ezSQLcore') ) die('<b>Fatal Error:</b> ezSQL_mysql requires ezSQLcore (ez_sql_core.php) to be included/loaded before it can be used');

    class ezSQL_mysql extends ezSQLcore
    {

        var $dbuser = false;
        var $dbpassword = false;
        var $dbname = false;
        var $dbhost = false;

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Constructor - allow the user to perform a qucik connect at the
        *  same time as initialising the ezSQL_mysql class
        */

        function ezSQL_mysql($dbuser='', $dbpassword='', $dbname='', $dbhost='localhost')
        {
            $this->dbuser = $dbuser;
            $this->dbpassword = $dbpassword;
            $this->dbname = $dbname;
            $this->dbhost = $dbhost;
        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Short hand way to connect to mySQL database server
        *  and select a mySQL database at the same time
        */

        function quick_connect($dbuser='', $dbpassword='', $dbname='', $dbhost='localhost')
            {
            $return_val = false;
            if ( ! $this->connect($dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbhost,true) ) ;
            else if ( ! $this->select($dbname) ) ;
            else $return_val = true;
            return $return_val;
            }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Try to connect to mySQL database server
        */

        function connect($dbuser='', $dbpassword='', $dbhost='localhost')
        {
            global $ezsql_mysql_str; $return_val = false;

            // Must have a user and a password
            if ( ! $dbuser )
            {
                $this->register_error($ezsql_mysql_str[1]);
                //$this->show_errors ? trigger_error($ezsql_mysql_str[1],E_USER_WARNING) : null;
                die($ezsql_mysql_str[1]);
            }
            // Try to establish the server database handle
            else if ( ! $this->dbh = @mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword,true) )
            {
                $this->register_error($ezsql_mysql_str[2].' in '.__FILE__.' on line '.__LINE__);
                $this->show_errors ? trigger_error($ezsql_mysql_str[2],E_USER_WARNING) : null;
            }
            else
            {
                if($this->log_to_file){
                    $fh=fopen($this->logfile,"a");
                    fwrite($fh,"Connect - " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()) . " - " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ."\n");
                    fclose($fh);
                }

                mysql_query ("SET time_zone = '".date("P")."'");
                mysql_query( 'set names utf8' );
                mysql_query ("set character_set_client='utf8'");
                mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
                mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");

                $this->dbuser = $dbuser;
                $this->dbpassword = $dbpassword;
                $this->dbhost = $dbhost;
                $return_val = true;
            }

            return $return_val;
        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Try to select a mySQL database
        */

        function select($dbname='')
        {
            global $ezsql_mysql_str; $return_val = false;

            // Must have a database name
            if ( ! $dbname )
        {
                $this->register_error($ezsql_mysql_str[3].' in '.__FILE__.' on line '.__LINE__);
                $this->show_errors ? trigger_error($ezsql_mysql_str[3],E_USER_WARNING) : null;
            }

            // Must have an active database connection
            else if ( ! $this->dbh )
            {
                $this->register_error($ezsql_mysql_str[4].' in '.__FILE__.' on line '.__LINE__);
                $this->show_errors ? trigger_error($ezsql_mysql_str[4],E_USER_WARNING) : null;
            }

            // Try to connect to the database
            else if ( !@mysql_select_db($dbname,$this->dbh) )
            {
                // Try to get error supplied by mysql if not use our own
                if ( !$str = @mysql_error($this->dbh))
                      $str = $ezsql_mysql_str[5];

                $this->register_error($str.' in '.__FILE__.' on line '.__LINE__);
                $this->show_errors ? trigger_error($str,E_USER_WARNING) : null;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->dbname = $dbname;
                $return_val = true;
            }

            return $return_val;
        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Format a mySQL string correctly for safe mySQL insert
        *  (no mater if magic quotes are on or not)
        */

        function escape($str)
        {
            return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Return mySQL specific system date syntax
        *  i.e. Oracle: SYSDATE Mysql: NOW()
        */

        function sysdate()
        {
            return 'NOW()';
        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Perform mySQL query and try to detirmin result value
        */

        function query($query)
        {

            // Initialise return
            $return_val = 0;

            // Flush cached values..
            $this->flush();

            // For reg expressions
            $query = trim($query);

            // Log how the function was called
            $this->func_call = "\$db->query(\"$query\")";

            // Keep track of the last query for debug..
            $this->last_query = $query;

            // Count how many queries there have been
            $this->num_queries++;

            // Use core file cache function
            if ( $cache = $this->get_cache($query) )
            {
                return $cache;
            }

            // If there is no existing database connection then try to connect
            if ( ! isset($this->dbh) || ! $this->dbh )
            {
                $this->connect($this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $this->dbhost);
                $this->select($this->dbname);
            }

            if($this->log_to_file){
                $mtime = microtime(); 
                $mtime = explode(' ', $mtime); 
                $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0]; 
                $starttime = $mtime;
            }

            // Perform the query via std mysql_query function..
            $this->result = @mysql_query($query,$this->dbh);

            if($this->log_to_file){
                $mtime = microtime(); 
                $mtime = explode(" ", $mtime); 
                $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0]; 
                $endtime = $mtime; 
                $totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime); 
                //if($totaltime > 0.001) {echo '<hr />' . $totaltime . ' - ' . $query . '<hr />';}

                $fh=fopen($this->logpath,"a");
                fwrite($fh,$totaltime . ' - ' . $query . "\n");
                fclose($fh);
            }

            // If there is an error then take note of it..
            if ( $str = @mysql_error($this->dbh) )
            {
                $is_insert = true;
                $this->register_error($str);
                $this->show_errors ? trigger_error($str,E_USER_WARNING) : null;
                return false;
            }

            // Query was an insert, delete, update, replace
            $is_insert = false;
            if ( preg_match("/^(insert|delete|update|replace)\s+/i",$query) )
            {
                $this->rows_affected = @mysql_affected_rows();

                // Take note of the insert_id
                if ( preg_match("/^(insert|replace)\s+/i",$query) )
                {
                    $this->insert_id = @mysql_insert_id($this->dbh);
                }

                // Return number fo rows affected
                $return_val = $this->rows_affected;
            }
            // Query was a select
            else
            {

                // Take note of column info
                $i=0;
                while ($i < @mysql_num_fields($this->result))
                {
                    $this->col_info[$i] = @mysql_fetch_field($this->result);
                    $i++;
                }

                // Store Query Results
                $num_rows=0;
                while ( $row = @mysql_fetch_object($this->result) )
                {
                    // Store relults as an objects within main array
                    $this->last_result[$num_rows] = $row;
                    $num_rows++;
                }

                @mysql_free_result($this->result);

                // Log number of rows the query returned
                $this->num_rows = $num_rows;

                // Return number of rows selected
                $return_val = $this->num_rows;
            }

            // disk caching of queries
            $this->store_cache($query,$is_insert);

            // If debug ALL queries
            $this->trace || $this->debug_all ? $this->debug() : null ;

            return $return_val;

        }

    }

    $db = new ezSQL_mysql(EZSQL_DB_USER, EZSQL_DB_PASSWORD, EZSQL_DB_NAME, EZSQL_DB_HOST);
    /*
    $db->show_errors = false;
    $db->quick_connect(EZSQL_DB_USER, EZSQL_DB_PASSWORD, EZSQL_DB_NAME, EZSQL_DB_HOST);
    if(count($db->captured_errors) > 0){
        global $main_smarty, $the_template;

        if(isset($main_smarty)){
            $main_smarty->compile_dir = "cache/templates_c/";
            $main_smarty->template_dir = "templates/";
            $main_smarty->cache_dir = "cache/";
            $main_smarty->config_dir = "";
            $main_smarty->force_compile = false; // has to be off to use cache
            $main_smarty->display($the_template . '/no_database.tpl');
            die();
        }
    } else {
        die('Error connection to the database.');
    }
    $db->show_errors = true;
    */

?>
```

Here is my `ez_sql_core.php file.

```
<?php
    /**********************************************************************
    *  Author: Justin Vincent (justin@visunet.ie)
    *  Web...: http://php.justinvincent.com
    *  Name..: ezSQL
    *  Desc..: ezSQL Core module - database abstraction library to make
    *          it very easy to deal with databases.
    *
    */

    /**********************************************************************
    *  ezSQL Constants
    */

    if(!defined('mnminclude')){header('Location: ../404error.php');die();}

    define('EZSQL_VERSION','2.03');
    define('OBJECT','OBJECT',true);
    define('ARRAY_A','ARRAY_A',true);
    define('ARRAY_N','ARRAY_N',true);
    define('EZSQL_CORE_ERROR','ezSQLcore can not be used by itself (it is designed for use by database specific modules).');


    /**********************************************************************
    *  Core class containg common functions to manipulate query result
    *  sets once returned
    */

    class ezSQLcore
    {

        var $trace            = false;  // same as $debug_all
        var $debug_all        = false;  // same as $trace
        var $debug_called     = false;
        var $vardump_called   = false;
        var $show_errors      = true;
        var $num_queries      = 0;
        var $last_query       = null;
        var $last_error       = null;
        var $col_info         = null;
        var $captured_errors  = array();
        var $cache_dir        = false;
        var $cache_queries    = false;
        var $cache_inserts    = false;
        var $use_disk_cache   = false;
        var $cache_timeout    = 24; // hours
        var $log_to_file      = false;  // create a file in your root pligg folder 
        var $logfile          = 'query.log';
        var $logpath          = 'query.log';                                                                    // named query.log and chmod 755

        // == TJH == default now needed for echo of debug function
        var $debug_echo_is_on = true;

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Constructor
        */

        function ezSQLcore()
        {
        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Connect to DB - over-ridden by specific DB class
        */

        function connect()
        {
            die(EZSQL_CORE_ERROR);
        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Select DB - over-ridden by specific DB class
        */

        function select()
        {
            die(EZSQL_CORE_ERROR);
        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Basic Query  - over-ridden by specific DB class
        */

        function query()
        {
            die(EZSQL_CORE_ERROR);
        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Format a string correctly for safe insert - over-ridden by specific
        *  DB class
        */

        function escape()
        {
            die(EZSQL_CORE_ERROR);
        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Return database specific system date syntax
        *  i.e. Oracle: SYSDATE Mysql: NOW()
        */

        function sysdate()
        {
            die(EZSQL_CORE_ERROR);
        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Print SQL/DB error - over-ridden by specific DB class
        */

        function register_error($err_str)
        {
            // Keep track of last error
            $this->last_error = $err_str;

            // Capture all errors to an error array no matter what happens
            $this->captured_errors[] = array
            (
                'error_str' => $err_str,
                'query'     => $this->last_query
            );
        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Turn error handling on or off..
        */

        function show_errors()
        {
            $this->show_errors = true;
        }

        function hide_errors()
        {
            $this->show_errors = false;
        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Kill cached query results
        */

        function flush()
        {
            // Get rid of these
            $this->last_result = null;
            $this->col_info = null;
            $this->last_query = null;
            $this->from_disk_cache = false;
        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Get one variable from the DB - see docs for more detail
        */

        function get_var($query=null,$x=0,$y=0)
        {

            // Log how the function was called
            $this->func_call = "\$db->get_var(\"$query\",$x,$y)";

            // If there is a query then perform it if not then use cached results..
            if ( $query )
            {
                $this->query($query);
            }

            // Extract var out of cached results based x,y vals
            if ( $this->last_result[$y] )
            {
                $values = array_values(get_object_vars($this->last_result[$y]));
            }

            // If there is a value return it else return null
            return (isset($values[$x]) && $values[$x]!=='')?$values[$x]:null;
        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Get one row from the DB - see docs for more detail
        */

        function get_row($query=null,$output=OBJECT,$y=0)
        {

            // Log how the function was called
            $this->func_call = "\$db->get_row(\"$query\",$output,$y)";

            // If there is a query then perform it if not then use cached results..
            if ( $query )
            {
                $this->query($query);
            }

            // If the output is an object then return object using the row offset..
            if ( $output == OBJECT )
            {
                return $this->last_result[$y]?$this->last_result[$y]:null;
            }
            // If the output is an associative array then return row as such..
            elseif ( $output == ARRAY_A )
            {
                return $this->last_result[$y]?get_object_vars($this->last_result[$y]):null;
            }
            // If the output is an numerical array then return row as such..
            elseif ( $output == ARRAY_N )
            {
                return $this->last_result[$y]?array_values(get_object_vars($this->last_result[$y])):null;
            }
            // If invalid output type was specified..
            else
            {
                $this->print_error(" \$db->get_row(string query, output type, int offset) -- Output type must be one of: OBJECT, ARRAY_A, ARRAY_N");
            }

        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Function to get 1 column from the cached result set based in X index
        *  see docs for usage and info
        */

        function get_col($query=null,$x=0)
        {

            // If there is a query then perform it if not then use cached results..
            if ( $query )
            {
                $this->query($query);
            }

            // Extract the column values
            for ( $i=0; $i < count($this->last_result); $i++ )
            {
                $new_array[$i] = $this->get_var(null,$x,$i);
            }

            if(!isset($new_array)){$new_array = array();}

            return $new_array;
        }


        /**********************************************************************
        *  Return the the query as a result set - see docs for more details
        */

        function get_results($query=null, $output = OBJECT)
        {

            // Log how the function was called
            $this->func_call = "\$db->get_results(\"$query\", $output)";

            // If there is a query then perform it if not then use cached results..
            if ( $query )
            {
                $this->query($query);
            }

            // Send back array of objects. Each row is an object
            if ( $output == OBJECT )
            {
                return $this->last_result;
            }
            elseif ( $output == ARRAY_A || $output == ARRAY_N )
            {
                if ( $this->last_result )
                {
                    $i=0;
                    foreach( $this->last_result as $row )
                    {

                        $new_array[$i] = get_object_vars($row);

                        if ( $output == ARRAY_N )
                        {
                            $new_array[$i] = array_values($new_array[$i]);
                        }

                        $i++;
                    }

                    return $new_array;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }


        /**********************************************************************
        *  Function to get column meta data info pertaining to the last query
        * see docs for more info and usage
        */

        function get_col_info($info_type="name",$col_offset=-1)
        {

            if ( $this->col_info )
            {
                if ( $col_offset == -1 )
                {
                    $i=0;
                    foreach($this->col_info as $col )
                    {
                        $new_array[$i] = $col->{$info_type};
                        $i++;
                    }
                    return $new_array;
                }
                else
                {
                    return $this->col_info[$col_offset]->{$info_type};
                }

            }

        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  store_cache
        */

        function store_cache($query,$is_insert)
        {

            // The would be cache file for this query
            $cache_file = $this->cache_dir.'/'.md5($query);

            // disk caching of queries
            if ( $this->use_disk_cache && ( $this->cache_queries && ! $is_insert ) || ( $this->cache_inserts && $is_insert ))
            {
                if ( ! is_dir($this->cache_dir) )
                {
                    $this->register_error("Could not open cache dir: $this->cache_dir");
                    $this->show_errors ? trigger_error("Could not open cache dir: $this->cache_dir",E_USER_WARNING) : null;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Cache all result values
                    $result_cache = array
                    (
                        'col_info' => $this->col_info,
                        'last_result' => $this->last_result,
                        'num_rows' => $this->num_rows,
                        'return_value' => $this->num_rows,
                    );
                    error_log ( serialize($result_cache), 3, $cache_file);
                }
            }

        }

        function un_cache($query) 
            { 
                $cache_file = $this->cache_dir.'/'.md5($query);          
                if ( $this->use_disk_cache && $this->cache_queries && file_exists($cache_file) ) 
                { 
                    unlink($cache_file); 
                } 
            } 

        /**********************************************************************
        *  get_cache
        */

        function get_cache($query)
        {

            // The would be cache file for this query
            $cache_file = $this->cache_dir.'/'.md5($query);

            // Try to get previously cached version
            if ( $this->use_disk_cache && $this->cache_queries && file_exists($cache_file) )
            {
                // Only use this cache file if less than 'cache_timeout' (hours)
                if ( (time() - filemtime($cache_file)) > ($this->cache_timeout*3600) || (filesize($cache_file) > 2000000) )
                {
                    unlink($cache_file);
                }
                else
                {
                    $result_cache = unserialize(file_get_contents($cache_file));

                    $this->col_info = $result_cache['col_info'];
                    $this->last_result = $result_cache['last_result'];
                    $this->num_rows = $result_cache['num_rows'];

                    $this->from_disk_cache = true;

                    // If debug ALL queries
                    $this->trace || $this->debug_all ? $this->debug() : null ;

                    return $result_cache['return_value'];
                }
            }

        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Dumps the contents of any input variable to screen in a nicely
        *  formatted and easy to understand way - any type: Object, Var or Array
        */

        function vardump($mixed='')
        {

            // Start outup buffering
            ob_start();

            echo "<p><table><tr><td bgcolor=ffffff><blockquote><font color=000090>";
            echo "<pre><font face=arial>";

            if ( ! $this->vardump_called )
            {
                echo "<font color=800080><b>ezSQL</b> (v".EZSQL_VERSION.") <b>Variable Dump..</b></font>\n\n";
            }

            $var_type = gettype ($mixed);
            print_r(($mixed?$mixed:"<font color=red>No Value / False</font>"));
            echo "\n\n<b>Type:</b> " . ucfirst($var_type) . "\n";
            echo "<b>Last Query</b> [$this->num_queries]<b>:</b> ".($this->last_query?$this->last_query:"NULL")."\n";
            echo "<b>Last Function Call:</b> " . ($this->func_call?$this->func_call:"None")."\n";
            echo "<b>Last Rows Returned:</b> ".count($this->last_result)."\n";
            echo "</font></pre></font></blockquote></td></tr></table>".$this->donation();
            echo "\n<hr size=1 noshade color=dddddd>";

            // Stop output buffering and capture debug HTML
            $html = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();

            // Only echo output if it is turned on
            if ( $this->debug_echo_is_on )
            {
                echo $html;
            }

            $this->vardump_called = true;

            return $html;

        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Alias for the above function
        */

        function dumpvar($mixed)
        {
            $this->vardump($mixed);
        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Displays the last query string that was sent to the database & a
        * table listing results (if there were any).
        * (abstracted into a seperate file to save server overhead).
        */

        function debug()
        {

            // Start outup buffering
            ob_start();

            echo "<blockquote>";

            // Only show ezSQL credits once..
            if ( ! $this->debug_called )
            {
                echo "<font color=800080 face=arial size=2><b>ezSQL</b> (v".EZSQL_VERSION.") <b>Debug..</b></font><p>\n";
            }

            if ( $this->last_error )
            {
                echo "<font face=arial size=2 color=000099><b>Last Error --</b> [<font color=000000><b>$this->last_error</b></font>]<p>";
            }

            if ( $this->from_disk_cache )
            {
                echo "<font face=arial size=2 color=000099><b>Results retrieved from disk cache</b></font><p>";
            }

            echo "<font face=arial size=2 color=000099><b>Query</b> [$this->num_queries] <b>--</b> ";
            echo "[<font color=000000><b>$this->last_query</b></font>]</font><p>";

                echo "<font face=arial size=2 color=000099><b>Query Result..</b></font>";
                echo "<blockquote>";

            if ( $this->col_info )
            {

                // =====================================================
                // Results top rows

                echo "<table cellpadding=5 cellspacing=1 bgcolor=555555>";
                echo "<tr bgcolor=eeeeee><td nowrap valign=bottom><font color=555599 face=arial size=2><b>(row)</b></font></td>";


                for ( $i=0; $i < count($this->col_info); $i++ )
                {
                    echo "<td nowrap align=left valign=top><font size=1 color=555599 face=arial>{$this->col_info[$i]->type} {$this->col_info[$i]->max_length}</font><br><span style='font-family: arial; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold;'>{$this->col_info[$i]->name}</span></td>";
                }

                echo "</tr>";

                // ======================================================
                // print main results

            if ( $this->last_result )
            {

                $i=0;
                foreach ( $this->get_results(null,ARRAY_N) as $one_row )
                {
                    $i++;
                    echo "<tr bgcolor=ffffff><td bgcolor=eeeeee nowrap align=middle><font size=2 color=555599 face=arial>$i</font></td>";

                    foreach ( $one_row as $item )
                    {
                        echo "<td nowrap><font face=arial size=2>$item</font></td>";
                    }

                    echo "</tr>";
                }

            } // if last result
            else
            {
                echo "<tr bgcolor=ffffff><td colspan=".(count($this->col_info)+1)."><font face=arial size=2>No Results</font></td></tr>";
            }

            echo "</table>";

            } // if col_info
            else
            {
                echo "<font face=arial size=2>No Results</font>";
            }

            echo "</blockquote></blockquote>".$this->donation()."<hr noshade color=dddddd size=1>";

            // Stop output buffering and capture debug HTML
            $html = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();

            // Only echo output if it is turned on
            if ( $this->debug_echo_is_on )
            {
                echo $html;
            }

            $this->debug_called = true;

            return $html;

        }

        /**********************************************************************
        *  Naughty little function to ask for some remuniration!
        */

        function donation()
        {
            return "<font size=1 face=arial color=000000>If ezSQL has helped <a href=\"https://www.paypal.com/xclick/business=justin%40justinvincent.com&item_name=ezSQL&no_note=1&tax=0\" style=\"color: 0000CC;\">make a donation!?</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;<!--[ go on! you know you want to! ]--></font>";
        }

    }

?>
```

What is a Strict Standards error and how can i resolve them?
I am currently running PHP 5.4 and getting the following errors

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of ezSQL_mysql::query() should be compatible with ezSQLcore::query() in /home2/africaf9/public_html/libs/db.php on line 37

Strict Standards: Declaration of ezSQL_mysql::escape() should be compatible with ezSQLcore::escape() in /home2/africaf9/public_html/libs/db.php on line 37
```

Any help will be appreciated. Let me know if i can provide you with any further details.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the function signature of all 4 functions? You code only has `ezSQL_mysql`, not `ezSQLcore`.

Comment: the method signatures dont match. You could reduce your error reporting level to hide the errors, but that SQL wrapper appears to be ancient (the mysql_* api it relies on has been removed from the current version of php) so better to just use something else.